# best practice - upgrade dojo/dijit to dojo2 application

Tags: dojo

We have a legacy PHP/Zend application built with dojo/dijit and dojox/mobile. We want to start to remodel the application using DOJO2. Much of the existing UI is already in the form of dijit AJAX pulls against server code.

We've been through the dojo2 tutorials, as well as become fond of webstorm.

As folks do such migrations, is it most often done as a new, dojo2 application that makes pulls against legacy (existing) server code, or is it more common to point webstorm's 'dist' directory to the existing application's javascript folder and create 'stub' server pages that just include the new DOJO2 code.

Or does it not really matter?

We're just looking to see what is the most common path forward with DOJO2 while minimizing the mucking that goes on with Zend's module routers, and don't want to start down a path that has some unknown 'gotchas'.

Answer (score 0):

Dojo 2 follows a reactive architecture and has a different build path to legacy Dojo. You may find it easier to re-write each php page's TS/JS code at a time to use Dojo 2. I'm afraid I am not familiar with Zend so cannot provide specific advice for this.